# Bullet-proofing C++ temporary lifetimes?

Tags: c++, c++17, lifetime

Revisiting lifetime extension in C++, I found out that there are some patterns that break "decomposability" of C++ expressions. For example, the following two blocks are a [valid C++ code](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5):

```
class NonMovable {
public:
   NonMovable(NonMovable&&) = delete;
   NonMovable(const NonMovable&) = delete;
   NonMovable();

   int Value() const;
};

template <class T>
const T& identity(const T& x) {
    return x;
}

template <class T>
class A {
public:
    explicit A(const T& value) : value_(value) {}
    const T& GetValue() const {
        return value_;
    }
private:
    const T& value_;
};
```

Correct usage:

```
int main() {
    int retcode = identity(
        identity(/*tmp1*/ A(/*tmp2*/ NonMovable{}).GetValue())).Value();
    // tmp1 and tmp2 end their lifetimes here: 
    // their full-expression is the whole previous line
    return retcode;
}
```

But if we decompose the first expression in `main`, it becomes invalid:

```
int main() {
    auto&& a_obj = /*tmp1*/ A(/*tmp2*/ NonMovable{});
    // tmp2 lifetime ends here

    // oops! dereferencing dangling reference:
    int retcode = identity(
        identity(a_obj.GetValue())).Value();
    return retcode;
    // tmp1 lifetime ends here
}
```

My question is:
**Is it possible to disable the second kind of usage?**

P.S.: I'm not really sure if the second `main` introduces UB, because I've [tested](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/iGI1ZG) it with `clang -Wlifetime`, and it doesn't complain. But I still believe it is UB. In real life I've came across a similar behaviour: the code broke, emmiting UBSan warnings and segfaults if I decomposed a single expression into two separate ones.

P.P.S.: those `identity`s don't really matter much, if I understand object lifetimes correctly (which I now doubt)

Comment: What do you mean by "bullet-proofing"? In C++ it is always developer's responsibility to ensure that objects are surviving for long enough to keep pointers and references to them valid.

Comment: This has been a problem since forever. For example, when `auto` was repurposed to its current day version, expression templates started having the exact issue shown here. That's why e.g. Eigen still has [a related common pitfall](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html). There's no real way to fix this.

Comment: @VTT well, yes, but I believe that the described behavior is insane even for C++. I've came across it when I decomposed an expression in some unit test, and it took me a long time to figure out what is going on. Disabling the second usage is the possible way to bullet proof

Comment: When it happened to me for the first time, UBSan issued warnings about alignment issues, and it is one of the reasons it took me very long to debug it

Comment: @MaxLanghof thanks for the reading. This is sad

Comment: What about deleting the r-value reference constructor of A `A(T&& )`?

Comment: @Albjenow it would disable the only correct usage

Comment: I find a lot of things about C++ insane (and it looks like ISO C++ committee is going to add even more). But you just need to [get used to it](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/027/509/You_get_used.png).

Comment: It makes it necessary to contruct `NotMovable` out-of-line which is (to me) the only reasonable option to use `A`.

Comment: For the record: Yes, it is still UB (https://godbolt.org/z/wON8ES member function called after destruction is certain UB, even if it compiles and runs without any warnings under `-Wlifetime`) and your understanding of the relevant lifetime rules appears to be correct.

Comment: @Albjenow If you consider this in the context of e.g. expression templates, then it is both reasonable, normal and expected to construct and evaluate a group of objects containing references to temporaries, as long as the final evaluation of the expression happens within the same full expression. In that case the issue is mitigated by _"don't use `auto` (and of course don't manually spell out the insane expression template instantiations that occur)"_ so that doing the right thing is the only valid option.

Comment: The most that can be done here is to explicitly delete the constructor overload: `explicit A(T &&value)=delete;` in order to ban passing temporaries to the constructor. This is not really an answer here since this will also cause the so-called "valid usage" to be ill-formed. But even though this usage is so-called "valid", you've just discovered how much of a minefield this is. Passing a reference to a constructor that saves it as a class member, except under very controlled conditions, is a ticking time bomb. The short answer is: don't. Just delete this overload.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I am not entirely sure about the complete list of usages but if `GetValue` should only be called on temporaries, it maybe qualified with `const &&`.

Comment: @Albijenow it doesn't save the situation -- the provided code would still compile, and will still be UB. Though it partially protects -- for example, if I used `auto` instead of `auto&&`

Comment: @NikitaPetrenko Actually it [would not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/eXSZal)... While I'm not convinced that it fixes _all_ problems, this does eliminate quite a few though. Good suggestion!

Comment: Wow, great. I guess it should be the answer then

Comment: @MaxLanghof I actually believe that `const&&` is better: https://godbolt.org/z/ckMenp

@Albjenow I would accept your answer if you write it, it is indeed a great idea

Comment: no, my solution gives false positives :( An explicit specialization of `std::move` for the needed classes would do it, I believe

Comment: No, partial specialization for template functions is not allowed :(

Comment: @MaxLanghof check this out: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8BQs4L

Comment: Would you want to allow `NonMovable nm; A a(nm); a.GetValue();`?

Answer (score 3):

Your analysis is correct. Without lifetime extension, all temporaries are destroyed at the end of the "full expression", i.e. the `;` at the end of the line. So when you say

```
int retcode = A(NonMovable{}).GetValue().Value();
```

(comments and `identity` calls removed for clarity) then everything is okay; the `NonMovable` object is still alive at the time you ask for its value.

On the other hand, when you say

```
auto&& a_obj = A(NonMovable{});
```

then the `NonMovable` is destroyed at the end of the line, and the `A` object will be holding a dangling reference. (As an aside, `auto&&` just lifetime-extends the temporary `A` here -- you may as well just use plain `auto`)

> My question is: Is it possible to disable the second kind of usage?

Not really, at least as far as I know. You could add a deleted `A(NonMovable&&)` constructor, but this would also prevent "correct" usage as in the first example. The is exactly the same issue that occurs with `std::string_view` (and will occur with `std::span` in C++20) -- essentially, your `A` class has reference semantics, but is referring to a temporary which has been destroyed.

Comment: I'm sorry for this very long line of comments under the question -- but I believe there exists an almost satisfactory solution -- at least it explicitly asks not to use `std::move`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r6IlOm

Though the proposed solution doesn't commute with `identity`, it actually is the problem of `identity`.

Answer (score 1):

So by using collective mind, in the comments under the question we've managed to come up with the following implementation of `A`, which might be applicable to some use cases (but not `std::span` or `std::string_view` usage):

```
struct Dummy;

template <class T>
class A {
public:
    explicit A(const T& value) : value_(value) {}

    template <class TDummy = Dummy>
    const T& GetValue() const& {
        static_assert(!std::is_same_v<TDummy, Dummy>, 
        "Stop and think, you're doing something wrong!" 
        "And in any case, don't use std::move on this class!");
    }

    const T& GetValue() && {
        return value_;
    }
private:
    const T& value_;
};
```

Now, if one tries to compile the following code, he will get a descriprive error message:

```
int main() {
    auto&& a_obj = A(NonMovable{});
    // will not compile:
    int retcode = identity(
        identity(a_obj.GetValue())).Value();
    return retcode;
}
```

The reason is that `decltype((a_obj)) == A<NonMovable>&`, so it binds to the method that produces a compile time error.

It satisfies my use cases, but, sadly, this is not a universal solution -- it depends on what one wants from `class A`.